# Performance of multiple MapFragments (Android Map API v2)

Tags: android, google-maps, mapfragment

I searched the docs of the new [Google Android Map API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/), but didn't find anything about it. Before v2 we (officially) couldn't properly display more than one map per application (process). I assume that with `MapFragment` implementation it's no longer an issue. I also know, that `Fragments` can be self-contained since API 17. And, last but not least, there is compatibility package, which makes it possible to port it all back to at least API 8 (in API 7, there's no OpenGL 2.0 so the maps wouldn't work afaik).

Sa I have all the ingredients to port my app to Maps API v2 and implement the following scenario: `ViewPager` contains `Fragments` and each of them contains a `MapFragment`.

But should I do it? I mean, **would I face performance issues** if I had e.g. 20 `Fragments` containing `MapFragments` in a `ViewPager`?

If you found anything that addresses my concern in the docs or somewhere else, please tell me.

---

**EDIT: Example usage**: Let's imagine a screen containing informations about some specific item - place, event, article. Also let's imagine that, among other informations, it must contain a map to be fully functional. But I would like the user to be able to swipe to another item if he wants. Each item has its own map.

Side note: I know that I can implement one map outside the `ViewPager` and just update it based on the currently displayed item, but it's not what I'm looking for - it's not user-centered design.

---

**Possible solution** (but not checked yet). `ViewPager` only keeps a few (default - 3) Fragments in it's cache and recreates them when they're about to show up, so there won't be much memory overhead as only a few `MapFragments` are needed. The performance problem may be the `MapFragment` inflation which is quite heavy, I believe - but that can be solved with recycling of `MapFragments`.

---

So why won't I implement it if I believe it will work nice? There's another problem which makes it impossible to move `MapFragments` without the app look like it's broken. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419521/moving-mapfragment-surfaceview-causes-black-background-flickering).

Comment: Have you made any tests?

Comment: No, because this API is flawed in so many ways, it's not worth it to implement in many cases (my included)

Answer (score 1):

You could easily test it but my guess is that it would very much depend on the phone as Maps still is fairly heavy to run.

That said I'd never recommend this kind of user navigation. A map can already be swiped at so why would you add ViewPager swipe as well? This would make a very confusing user experience. If you want to switch between different views/point of interests you should add buttons (overflow menu buttons preferred as in the navigation app) or something similar that helps the user navigate around.

Comment: I know I could test it, but only on two devices. When I asked the question (it's quite old now) I was concerned about the performance on older devices running e.g. Android 2.2 and I have none to test on (impossible to test performance on emulator). As to the usage: see my edit for explanation where it may be useful.  I also added a possible solution.

Comment: @MichałK yes but swiping between multiple maps just doesn't make much sense. But from experience I can tell on some 2.2 and 2.3 devices it runs fine with multiple mapfragments in tabs (not my layout idea).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you definitely would run into performance issues because `ViewPager` doesn't employ view recycling by default; you can even bloat it with `ImageView`s let alone MapFragments.

As far as caching and recreating fragments in `ViewPager` - there's a [HorizontalListView](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34) lib that'd probably save you the effort as it does support view recycling.

Comment: It doesn't employ View recycling but it **does** employ Fragment recycling pretty much the same way as any AdapterView via `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `MyFragment.newInstance()` pattern.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, thanks. So the question that remains is whether `MapFragment` saves a big enough amount of state to pose a performance threat. I'd maybe try to inspect `FragmentManager`'s state with in the debugger or dump mem and use Eclipse MAT to figure out the amount of mem retained by fragments with no view hierarchy.

Comment: Now I think that it doesn't pose a mem threat (see my question edit which I added today), because there'll be at most 3 `MapFragments` at the same time. The only thing I worry about is the inflation, but that can be solved with recycling of the `MapView`. But I can't check it, because I spend my whole time on another project now. If you happen to check it, please update your answer and I'll be more than happy to accept it